# CSS - Placing elements results in scrollbar with relative and absolute. Why?

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm creating a page with a table and a header with some options, and I'm trying to put elements in position. One thing I want to do is to create a menu to show and hide columns. During the positioning process, I'm encountering the following result:

[image]

Here's my HTML markup and CSS:

```css
.conte-tabela {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.conte-tabela #cabecalho {
  background: #474241;
  border-left: 1px solid #312e2d;
  border-right: 1px solid #312e2d;
  border-top: 1px solid #312e2d;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Safari */
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  /* Konqueror HTML */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none;
  /* Non-prefixed version, currently supported by Chrome and Opera */
}

.conte-tabela #cabecalho #titulo {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 38px;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.conte-tabela #cabecalho #opcoes {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 38px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.conte-tabela #cabecalho #opcoes button {
  background-color: #474241;
  border: 1px solid #312e2d;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 40px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

.conte-tabela #cabecalho #opcoes #bot-pesquisa {
  background-image: url("/app/imagens/ico-pesquisa.png");
}

.conte-tabela #cabecalho #opcoes #bot-colunas {
  background-image: url("/app/imagens/ico-conf.png");
}

.conte-tabela #cabecalho #opcoes button:ACTIVE {
  background-color: #312e2d;
}

.conte-tabela #cabecalho #menu-colunas {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="conte-tabela" th:fragment="tabela-teste (titulo)">

  <!-- HEADER -->
  <div id="cabecalho">

    <!-- TITLE -->
    <span id="titulo" th:text="${titulo}">Título de tabela</span>

    <!-- BUTTONS (OPTIONS) -->
    <span id="opcoes">
      <button id="bot-pesquisa"></button><button id="bot-colunas"></button>
     </span>

    <!-- COLUMNS MENU -->
    <ul id="menu-colunas">
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" th:value="1">
        <label>1</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" th:value="2">
        <label>2</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" th:value="3">
        <label>3</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

**Note:** Some of tags are special tags. I'm a Java developer, and I'm using [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thvsjsp.html).

How can I fix this? How can I get rid of the scrollbar and also how can I reveal the missing part of the columns menu?

I know my CSS code is wrong, I just do not know where. Being an HTML marker is not my strong part...

Can somebody help me, please? Thanks in advance.

### EDIT 1

Here is an outline/sketch of the desired result:

[image]

### EDIT 2

I do not know if this is possible, but the header should keep the following layout format (in relation to the spaces between edges/borders):

[image]

Comment: `.conte-tabela #cabecalho #menu-colunas {` - remove `position: absolute`. Blocks with `position: absolute;` can't expand parent block. If block has `position: absolute; display: inline-block;` --> `display: inline-block;` will be ignored

Comment: You've got a `top:50%` on your class `.conte-tabela #cabecalho #menu-colunas` If you want the column to be in the top left you need to use `top:0; left;0`

Comment: @ArturMoroz Hello. I did what you said, and it did not work. It got rid of scrollbar, but the column menu is not positioned and fills the entire header. Do you know something else that I can do? And Thanks, anyway! :)

Comment: @Kiz Hello! Well, thats not what I want. Can you check my edit, please? Thank you, anyway!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/verstalo/ap6tyLkt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a height value to #cabecalho and add overflow: visible. 
Position #menu-colunas by adding right: 0.

**Updated** 
Take #menu-colunas out of #cabecalho and wrap both of them using a div. Then add position: relative to that wrapper.

See the updated code [here.](https://codepen.io/prakashom2new/pen/pRYeNN)

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;  
}
```

Comment: Maybe I can not give a fixed height to the header. See my second edition in my question, please. What do you think? And thank you for your attention.